# Change Blender Render Save Default to RGB from RGBA

Tags: rendering

Is there a way to change the default for saving a render to RGB instead of RGBA? This saves me disk space when working with renders that don't have an alpha-channel anyways.

I can't find anything on it under Edit > Preferences

[image: Render Screen]

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your preferences as a startup blend-file.

- Create new default blend-file
- Change the image format settings in <kbd>Output Properties > Output</kbd>
- Save the blend-file
- State the blend-file as the default startup blend-file <kbd>Info Editor > File> Defaults > Save Startup File</kbd>

Make sure you're in the saved blend-file when you state the blend as the startup default!

**Note:** I'm not sure if this overwrites previously saved blend-file defaults.

Unfortunately I think not. But it should for all future saved blends.